# Is there a way to find the time difference within a single datetime column, grouped by ID?

Tags: r, time, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
                              ID      DATE
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:07 AM
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:30 AM
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:31 AM
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:32 AM
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:33 AM
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:34 AM
                               A      12/18/2019 1:26:34 AM
                               B      12/18/2019 1:26:37 AM
                               B      12/18/2019 1:26:38 AM
```

Desired outcome:

```
                                 Duration of A 27 secs
                                 Duration of B  1 secs
```

I wish to accurately group by ID and find the time duration accurately.
I have tried splitting the date time into starttime and endtime, but this is not
yielding the correct result. I am not sure if I should create a loop?

So far, I have entered this command, and am not getting the correct result:

```
        diff<-data %>% 
             mutate (Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) %>%
             group_by(ID) %>% 
             summarise(timediff = difftime(first(DATE), last(DATE))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
I will continue to research this.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide data as a `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))` to aid reproducibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `difftime` to work you need arguments in reverse order.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(DATE = lubridate::mdy_hms(DATE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(timediff = difftime(last(DATE), first(DATE)))

#  ID    timediff
#  <fct> <drtn>  
#1 A     27 secs 
#2 B      1 secs
```

This can also be done in base R :

```
data$DATE <- as.POSIXct(data$DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
aggregate(DATE~ID, data, function(x) difftime(x[length(x)], x[1L]))
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), DATE = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("12/18/2019 1:26:07 AM", 
"12/18/2019 1:26:30 AM", "12/18/2019 1:26:31 AM", "12/18/2019 1:26:32 AM", 
"12/18/2019 1:26:33 AM", "12/18/2019 1:26:34 AM", "12/18/2019 1:26:37 AM", 
"12/18/2019 1:26:38 AM"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA,-9L))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. Is the default in seconds? Or do I need to add units = secs

Comment: @TanishaHudson I think it automatically selects the relevant units. You can specify `units = "secs"` in `difftime` if you always want them in seconds.